# Is there a way to treat Ping-Host as a boolean in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ping

I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (Ping-Host server1) { blah }
```

Anyone know of a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if ($(Ping-Host server1 -count 1 -timeout 10).received -eq 1) { blah }
```

Comment: Exactly like that.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on PowerShell 2.0 I would recommend using Test-Connection -Quiet.  It returns a simple true or false indicating whether or not the host can be reached via ping.  BTW one of the benefits of Test-Connection is it's built-in whereas ping-host isn't.