# Convert Test-Connection into Boolean

Tags: powershell, ping

I am using Powershell version 2, so I am unable to use Ping-Host as explained here
[Is there a way to treat Ping-Host as a boolean in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595298/is-there-a-way-to-treat-ping-host-as-a-boolean-in-powershell)

I can use test connection, i.e.

```
Test-Connection *ip_address* -count 1
```

I am trying to make this into a boolean, but it is not working

```
if ($(test-connection server -count 1).received -eq 1) { write-host "blah" } else {write-host "blah blah"}
```

The server I am able to ping outputs "blah blah", as if I am not able to ping it.

On the other hand, if I ping an unreachable server, I get error message

> Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer *server* failed:
>   Error due to lack of resources At line:1 char:22
>   + if ($(test-connection <<<<  *server* -count 1).received -eq 1) { write-host "blah" } else {write-host "blah blah"}
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (*server*:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand

And at the end it still outputs "blah blah".

How to fix?

Comment: I came across this question looking for a fast way to ping/test-connection/test-netconnection.  I settled on this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fast-asynchronous-ping-IP-d0a5cf0e/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Received** isn't a property of the object that **Test-Connection** returns, so `$(test-connection server -count 1).received` evaluates to null. You're overthinking it; just use `if (Test-Connection -Count 1)`. To suppress the error message, use **-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue**, or pipe the command to **Out-Null**. Either of the following will work:

```
if (Test-Connection server -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { write-host "blah" } else {write-host "blah blah"}
```

or

```
if (Test-Connection server -Count 1 | Out-Null) { write-host "blah" } else {write-host "blah blah"}
```

Answer (score 28):

Try the `-Quiet` switch:

```
Test-Connection server -Count 1 -Quiet    

-Quiet [<SwitchParameter>]
    Suppresses all errors and returns $True if any pings succeeded and $False if all failed.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: I know, right? this is ___EXACTLY___ what this switch was designed for, right down to suppressing errors

Answer (score 1):

a better one liner which we use at production

```
function test_connection_ipv4($ipv4) { if (test-connection $ipv4 -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) {$true} else {$false} }
```

usage example 1:

```
test_connection_ipv4 10.xx.xxx.50
True
```

usage example 2:

```
test_connection_ipv4 10.xx.xxx.51
False
```